# How to call an array that contains both one dimensional values and multi dimensional values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to change the values for statikk_start(2), statikk_start(3) and statikk_start(4). When the values of statikk_start changes from just singular values (integers) to a range of values, i don't know how i call them to the Rs() calculation. I want Rs to loop through each value of statikk_start. I've tried using the Select Case, but it gives me out of range error for case 3, 4 and 5.

```
    Dim p As Range
    Set p = Sheets("Kjøreplan").Range("B4:K27")

    Dim p_max As Range
    Set p_max = Sheets("Kjøreplan").Range("S36:Y36")

    Dim statikk_start As Variant
    statikk_start = Array(6, 10, 12, 12, 12, 6, 6)

    For i = 0 To UBound(statikk_start)
        Select Case i
            Case 2
                statikk_start(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets("Kjøreplan").Range("E4:E27").Value)
            Case 3
                statikk_start(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets("Kjøreplan").Range("G4:G27").Value)
            Case 4
                statikk_start(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets("Kjøreplan").Range("I4:I27").Value)
        End Select
    Next i

    Dim Rs(1 To 7) As Variant
    
    For colIndex = 1 To 7
        Select Case colIndex
            Case 1, 2, 6, 7
                Rs(colIndex) = 2 * p_max(1, colIndex) / statikk_start(colIndex - 1)
            Case 3
            For rowIndex = 1 To 24
                Rs(colIndex) = 2 * p_max(1, colIndex) / statikk_start(colIndex - 1)(2, rowIndex)
            Next rowIndex
            Case 4
            For rowIndex = 1 To 24
                Rs(colIndex) = 2 * p_max(1, colIndex) / statikk_start(colIndex - 1)(3, rowIndex)
            Next rowIndex
            Case 5
            For rowIndex = 1 To 24
                Rs(colIndex) = 2 * p_max(1, colIndex) / statikk_start(colIndex - 1)(4, rowIndex)
            Next rowIndex
        End Select
    Next colIndex
```

Comment: When you use `statikk_start(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets("Kjøreplan").Range("E4:E27").Value)` you load the jagged array with **a 1D type array**. This is what `Transpose` (for a column) does. Then, trying `statikk_start(colIndex - 1)(2, rowIndex)` makes no sense in a  1D array. So, you may use  `statikk_start(colIndex - 1)(rowIndex)` . The transposed array is 1D, **1 based**... Or not use `Transpose` anymore and do it as for 2D arrays. But being a column array, I think you should use `(rowIndex, 1)`. A column array (E:E, G:G, I:I) has only one column...

Comment: Why don't you share the whole code so we can properly test it?

Comment: When `statikk_start(i)` is an array do you expect an array of values in `Rs(i+1)` ?  Currently you're just re-assigning a single value for every iteration of `rowIndex`

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for something more like this?
Assume you want to transform each value in any arrays stored in `statikk_start`, before assigning the transformed array to `Rs`...

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim p As Range, p_max As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim statikk_start As Variant, pVal
    Dim Rs(1 To 7) As Variant
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Kjøreplan")
    Set p = ws.Range("B4:K27")         'not used?
    Set p_max = ws.Range("S36:Y36")

    statikk_start = Array(6, 10, 12, 12, 12, 6, 6)

    'no need for loop or Select Case
    statikk_start(2) = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("E4:E27").Value)
    statikk_start(3) = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("G4:G27").Value)
    statikk_start(4) = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("I4:I27").Value)
   
    For colIndex = 1 To p_max.Columns.Count
        pVal = p_max(1, colIndex)
        v = statikk_start(colIndex - 1)
        If IsArray(v) Then   'is the value an array?
            'transform the array before assigning it to Rs
            For RowIndex = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
                v(RowIndex) = 2 * pVal / v(RowIndex)
            Next RowIndex
            Rs(colIndex) = v
        Else
            Rs(colIndex) = 2 * pVal / v
        End If
    Next colIndex
End Sub
```